# Where on Stack Exchange can I ask questions about publicity of scientific research/advances?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where on Stack Exchange can I ask questions about publicity of scientific research/advances? For example, I want to ask why research advances such as [this one](https://techxplore.com/news/2019-11-scientists-artificial-leaf-carbon-fuel.html) rarely go beyond the lab, even though they may have enormous potential.

Comment: Here is the question https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/144574/why-do-breakthroughs-in-science-and-research-that-have-enormous-and-obvious-po

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [academia stack exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) will answer questions about how scientific research gets published, and why some research gets published while other research doesn't.

In this specific case, if you want to ask the chemistry community if the science behind that article is legit and/or whether or not it would pass the tests required for publication, you could try the [chemistry stack exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).

There is also a proposal for a stack exchange on [materials science](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=OTFkNDY1MDhhYTg4MWJjMzYxNmNmYWNkY2VjNzQ5ZTJjNjVmMjkwMGU1MjI1OGYyMWJkMjg5ZTA1NmM0MGMzZI6YUv-4c--1-P1Ng5SiOeYGnO17AGkMbBDOb2ICFcZd0) which already has example questions about solar cells, energy storage, materials for batteries and materials for energy conversion, but it will need about 65 more experienced stack exchange users to commit to it, in order for it to get launched.